# jQuery - Accessing Dynamically Built Elements

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox titled "Number of questions" where a user enters an integer. Whenever they enter a number, the following code is ran:

```
$('#dmc_mc_questionCount').keyup(function() {
    var amount = $(this).val();

    add_to = "";
    for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
       var current = i + 1;
       add_to = add_to + current + "<input type='input' name='data[Section][mc_answers][]' value='" + i +"' id='mc_answers_" + i + "' maxlength='1'> ";
    }

    $('#mc_answer_key').html(add_to); 
});
```

The following code works:

```
<span id="test">Test</span>

$('#test').click(function() {
    var x = $('#mc_answers_0').val();
    alert(x);
});
```

But the following does not:

```
$('#mc_answers_0').click(function() {
    alert('d');
});
```

Why can't I access #mc_answers_0?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#mc_answers_0', function() {
    alert('d');
});
```

`#mc_answers_0` doesn't exist at DOM ready, so you're handler never takes.